# Regular expression file extensions

Tags: regex

What is the regular expression for all files which end on

```
"*.med"
```

but not

```
"*.result.med"
```

?

I tried

```
((?!.result.med).med$)
```

without success. I does give all .med files including .result.med files.

Comment: `str.endsWith(".med") && !str.endsWith(".result.med")` - why regex? Please explain what the platform/language/tool is? Are you sure you need a regex? You posted some wildcard patterns (glob patterns?)

Comment: I need regex because it is used as an command line argument for a software wihtout source code

Comment: And what is the regex flavor? Have you tried anything?

Comment: look at my updated question

Comment: What's happening here? Almost 20 minutes and no answers on a `regex` question? It usually takes seconds! =D  BTW, tried myself and couldn't find an answer.

Comment: Try `^(?!.*\.result\.med$).*\.med$`

Comment: Are you sure `*.med` is a regex? I think the `*` is actually the command line wildcard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a lookbehind instead of a lookahead here :
`^.*(?<!\.result)\.med$`
Your lookahead does not work because for a file `*.result.med`, when the regex engine positionned just before the last dot, it checks if there is `.result.med` (there isn't, because what follows is `.med`) then matches `.med$`
You can also do this with a lookahead, but you need to do it this way :
`^(?!.*\.result.med$).*\.med$`